# add selector programmatically to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know this is a very simple question. I've searched stack overflow everywhere, and I always see the same answer. Yet it's still not working for me. I'm new to objective-C, please bear with me.

I am trying to add an action to my UIButton programmatically. This is inside an AVCaptureSession. here is my code:

```
// Create button and add to previewLayer:

UIButton *switchButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 50, (self.view.frame.size.height - 150), 100, 100)];

[switchButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(switchCameras)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
switchButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
switchButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
switchButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
[previewLayer addSublayer:switchButton.layer];


// Method switchCameras:

- (void)switchCameras {
printf("This is a neat command!");
}
```

When I tap the button, nothing happens, nothing prints to the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you never add the button to the view. You only add the layer. It is the button view (not the layer) that handles the event.

Replace this line:

```
[previewLayer addSublayer:switchButton.layer];
```

with something like:

```
[someView addSubview:switchButton];
```

`someView` should be an appropriate reference to whatever view you wish to add the button to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to give you the whole answer - just the info you need to find the answer for yourself.

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIControl`. The methods for adding target/actions to buttons are defined in UIIControl. Take a look at the Xcode docs on `UIControl`, and specifically look for a method who's name begins with `addTarget`.

If you can't figure it out, post back with a follow-on question with the problem you're having.

### EDIT:

@JoshCaswell just pointed out that your question already used `addTarget:action:`. I should have looked at your code more closely.

It looks like the problem is that you are adding the button's layer, not the button. Don't do that. Add the button as a subview of the appropriate container view. Layers don't handle target/action.

Comment: Oh dear. So there is. I missed that.